# Android: App crashes on app restart facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using a FragmentActivity as a holder. which displays LoginFragment, the problem arises when I call the app for the second time.

This particular crash is occurring when I have the app running, and I click on a Push notification (I think it starts the app, that's when the logcat gives me this):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.Collection.iterator()' on a null object reference
                at com.facebook.internal.Utility.isSubset(Utility.java:315)
                at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties.validatePermissions(LoginButton.java:151)
                at com.facebook.w

idget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties.setReadPermissions(LoginButton.java:126)
            at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(LoginButton.java:335)
            at com.joaquimley.sal15.fragments.LoginFragment.init(LoginFragment.java:90)
            at com.joaquimley.sal15.fragments.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:75)
```

And here it is the LoginFragment.java init() method:

```
v.findViewById(R.id.btn_no_login).setOnClickListener(this);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(FacebookHelper.getPermissions());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because your FacebookHelper.getPermissions() is returning a null value. If you look at the source code for Utility.java, it's iterating over the subset (which is what you pass in), and if that's throwing an NPE, it's because FacebookHelper.getPermissions() is giving you null.

Comment: The thing is.. This APP doesnt require any especial permissions, and it works fine, i went to the source code and found out that's something to do with the session being open ir not...